# Elm Type Svg.Svg has too few arguments

Tags: svg, elm

I am playing with [Elm time example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/time)  and trying to add more hands. To do it I extract code for hand like this:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  let
    angle =
      turns (Time.inMinutes model.time)
  in
    svg [ viewBox "0 0 100 100", width "300px" ]
      [ circle [ cx "50", cy "50", r "45", fill "#0B79CE" ] []
      , clockHand angle "#023963"
      ]

clockHand: Float -> String -> Svg -- PROBLEM HERE
clockHand angle color =
  let
    handX =
      toString (50 + 40 * cos angle)

    handY =
      toString (50 + 40 * sin angle)
  in
    line [ x1 "50", y1 "50", x2 handX, y2 handY, stroke color ] []
```

It works ok without the type declaration for `clockHand`, but when I add it - compiler returns me this:

```
-- TOO FEW ARGUMENTS -----------------------------------------------------------

Type Svg.Svg has too few arguments.

80| clockHand: Float -> String -> Svg

                                  ^^^
Expecting 1, but got 0.
```

Documentation for [line](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-svg/2.0.1/Svg#line)  tells that it has type

```
line : List Attribute -> List Svg -> Svg
```

Just as I was expecting. What did I miss here? What is the correct type? What arguments it is expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong docs. The correct version is here: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/1.1.1/Svg#line.

The type should be `Svg msg` rather than `Svg`.

This changed between Elm 0.16 and 0.17.

Comment: Oh, I see. And that msg means that apart from DOM, it could return events?

Comment: Exactly - that type would then be passed to your `update` function.